# Poner subitem en un listview

Tags: java, android, base-de-datos

Hola buenas quisiera poner un subitem en mi listview pero no lo consigo.
Este es mi activity_list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lista"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
```

Esta es mi clase lista

```
public class Lista extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lv ;
ArrayList<String> lista;
ArrayAdapter adaptador;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista);
    DbHelper db = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext(),null,null,1);
    lista = db.llenar_lv();
    adaptador = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lista);
    lv.setAdapter(adaptador);


}
```

}

Y este es el metodo llenas_lv

```
    public ArrayList llenar_lv(){
    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String q = "SELECT * FROM users";
    Cursor registros = db.rawQuery(q,null);
    registros.moveToFirst();

        while(registros.moveToNext()){
            lista.add(registros.getString(1));
            lista.add(registros.getString(2));

        }


    return lista;
}
```

Imagen quiero que me salga el subitem pero no lo consigo solo me sale del item 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error en el SimpleAdapter 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: a que te refieres con subitem? porque no creas un adapter personalizado?

Comment: no entiendo bien el concepto subitem si lo podrias explicar por favor, logro entender que al mantaner pulsado en un item quieres que te de ciertas opciones?

Comment: @diegoveloper Respuesta 1

Comment: @AshleyG.Respuesta 1

Comment: te vendría bien leer tutoriales:  https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial

Comment: @diegoveloper Y se puede sacar el subitem sin hacer un adapter personalizado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si podrías hacerlo sin necesidad de un Custom adapter, pero tienes que trabajar tu data.

Te quedaría algo así:

```
List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
     while(registros.moveToNext()){
     Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
        datum.put("datos1", registros.getString(1));
        datum.put("datos2", registros.getString(2));
        data.add(datum);
            }

    }
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data,
                                              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                                              new String[] {"datos1", "datos2"},
                                              new int[] {android.R.id.text1,
                                                         android.R.id.text2});
    itemList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Aquí tienes más info sobre el SimpleAdapter :
 [SimpleAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#SimpleAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20?%3E%3E,%20int,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29)

**UPDATE**

Actualizando tu código quedaría así :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista);
    DbHelper db = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext(),null,null,1);
    List<Map<String, String>> data = db.llenar_lv();
   SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data,
                                              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                                              new String[] {"datos1", "datos2"},
                                              new int[] {android.R.id.text1,
                                                         android.R.id.text2});
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


}



    public List<Map<String, String>> llenar_lv(){
    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String q = "SELECT * FROM users";
    Cursor registros = db.rawQuery(q,null);
    registros.moveToFirst();

       List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
     while(registros.moveToNext()){
     Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
        datum.put("datos1", registros.getString(1));
        datum.put("datos2", registros.getString(2));
        data.add(datum);
            }
       return data;
    }
```

Comment: No entiendo lo que hace ese SimpleAdapter @diegoveloper

Comment: Te agrega 2 valores en base a un Listado que contiene un Map con key value,   , el primer parámetro es el contexto, luego tu data, luego el layout (que tiene 2 elementos con ids, text1,text2,    el otro parametros es un array de los elementos que contiene tu data y finalmente el id de los layouts.

Comment: A vale, entonces tienes que hacer otro layout con 2 text view no??

Comment: en el ejemplo que te puse ahí está tomando layouts que ya existen de Android, puedes usarlos,  la otra forma más larga es hacer tu custom adapter con tu view personalizado como lo puse en los comentarios de tu pregunta.

Comment: Me salta error en el SimpleAdapter

Comment: que error te salta?

Comment: E actualizado con el error

Comment: revisa mi actualización

Comment: No me muestra nada

Comment: me olvidé el return data en el método : llenar_lv ya lo corregí

Comment: Ya esta, muchas gracias macho jajaja